# NoMethodError(undefined method 'article_URL') at redirect_to @article,

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the above error in my `ArticlesController`, here is the code:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new 
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

Routes configuration

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resource :articles
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `resources` instead of `resource`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Plural, not singular.

Comment: Glad to help. I recommend going through the rails guides to get a better understanding of how routing works: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html